# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on Chrome

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am facing strange Issue while doing the HTTP ajax post on Chrome. The below is the chrome event log where connection reset occurred on Chrome  which then tries to re-post and it got succeeded.

> Looking at timeline of both IIS and Chrome It looks IIS receives the request and
>   closed while doing some operation after 118278 ms. Since it's not a
>   graceful close Chrome tries to re-send and it's succeeded.

**Note:** Chrome 1st time used the existing socket connection and 2nd time it established the new socket connection

Question:

1. So what's happening here?. Is't due to any exception on server on
   1st time .. I see the status code as 64 on server which is "The
   specified network name is no longer available" which may be due to
   client. But from Chrome "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" will happen when server
   closes the connection.. So not sure where the problem is and how to
   analyse further.
2. If I Flush the existing socket connection on chrome before HTTP post
   then it works as well it works fine in "Edge" browser. 
        From angular can I flush the socket connection on HTTP post?

Need help to fix or trace the issue in detail

[image]
IIS Log

```
  2019-11-08 20:52:47 10.156.116.58 OPTIONS /api/asset/summary/save - 90 - 10.156.134.79 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/75.0.3770.100+Safari/537.36 http://test.com:90/ 200 0 0 157
2019-11-08 20:54:45 10.156.116.58 POST /api/asset/summary/save - 90 - 10.156.134.79 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/75.0.3770.100+Safari/537.36 http://test.com:90/ 0 0 64 118278
2019-11-08 20:55:04 10.156.116.58 POST /api/asset/summary/save - 90 - 10.156.134.79 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/75.0.3770.100+Safari/537.36 http://test.com:90/ 200 0 0 19123
2
```

Comment: Could you please post the details codes about how you use angular send the ajax post request?  Besides, I suggest you could try to compare the edge logs and chrome logs to check if there is any difference between them.

Comment: I tried comparing and i noticed no connection reset in edge while it was there on chrome. I fixed it by closing the connection on the response object from the API. I mean the connection wont be re-used so new connection was established.